Pinescript - plot shape in a given timeframe or lower
I'm trying to plot a shape on a chart whose timeframe is 10 minutes or lower and not display any plot in higher timeframe. I've tried the below code but the plot condition is not working and the plot is instead displayed in all timeframes. I'm using version 5.
plotTime = input.timeframe(defval="10", title="Plot Timeframe")  // time frame below which the shape is plotted. (E.g., 10 min)
currenttf = timeframe.in_seconds() / 60      // fetching the int value of current chart timeframe
plottf = timeframe.in_seconds(plotTime) / 60   //fetching the int value of plot timeframe
DISPLAY = currenttf<plottf ? display.all : display.none //plot if current timeframe is less than plot timeframe
plot(close, display=DISPLAY)

The above code displays the plot in all timeframes, please help.

Instead of using the display argument, just use it as a condition for the series argument.
DISPLAY = currenttf < plottf

plot(DISPLAY ? close : na)

